# phpredis persistent connect with nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: php, redis, persistent-connection, phpredis

I have classical server configuration schema with Nginx + PHP-FPM. Most of pages on my site contain data that saved into redis. Thus it is too many indirect (through php-fpm) lite requests to redis from many independent users. I use phpredis PHP extension to communicate with redis from PHP code. Can I use phpredis `pconnect()` method to decrease number of TCP connections between my backend servers and redis server? Should I expect no mush up of different users data within shared connections?

```
PHP version is 5.3.x
phpredis version is 2.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pconnect will definitely enable using existing connection and help decreasing the number of tcp connections thus enabling a better performance

Comment: I have enabled pconnect two months ago and everything works well. There is no one inter-users data mush up detected.